# Google map android direction

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-android-api-2

Am using the following code to open google map from my app with driving mode.

```
 String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr="+latitude+","+longitude+"&mode=driving";
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)); 
 intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
 startActivity(intent);
```

But Google map always showing  walking option as shown in image. Any way to change this ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `&dirflg=d` for driving directions.

So, now your code should look like this

```
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr="+latitude+","+longitude+"&dirflg=d";
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)); 
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Google map direction modes :

`dirflg=r - Switches on "Public Transit" (Railway direction)- only works in some areas.`

`dirflg=w - Switches to walking directions - still in beta.`

`dirflg=d - Switches to driving directions`